# How to change the date format in R

Tags: r, date, format

I have some date format as follow:

```
        V1  V2   V3
1 20100420 915   120
2 20100420 920   150
3 20100420 925   270
4 20100420 1530  281
```

3 columns per row, the 1th row means: 2010-04-20 09:15 120

now I want to change it to 1 column(time series):

```
                   V3
1 20100420 09:15   120
2 20100420 09:20   150
3 20100420 09:25   270
4 20100420 15:30   281
```

or:

```
                   V3
1 20100420 9:15    120
2 20100420 9:20    150
3 20100420 9:25    270
4 20100420 15:30   281
```

How could I achieve it in R?

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty well documented in the R docs and in different questions on SO.

Comment: For clarification, in the original data, what is `V3`?

Comment: it may be some data of stocks, the first two columns are the date, last columns may be `open.price`, `close.price`, `volumn`, ect.

Comment: Is the format of `V2` really only three digits? I assume that represents hours and minutes. Generally, that should be four digits. Is the time in 12-hour format or 24-hour format? You really should provide clearer information if you want people to help with answers.

Comment: yes, you are right, I didn't make it clear in the problem, I will edit it now.

Comment: And what about times before 1:00am? Are they just two digits? Or with a leading zero? Have you read these in as numeric or character? What does summary(yourdata) say?

Answer (score 5):

`?strptime` and `?sprintf` are your friends:

Recreate the dataset:

```
test <- read.table(textConnection("V1  V2 V3
20100420 915 120
20100420 920 150
20100420 925 270"),header=TRUE)
```

Do some pasting:

```
strptime(
paste(
    test$V1,
    sprintf("%04d", test$V2),
    sep=""
),
format="%Y%m%d%H%M"
)
```

Result:

```
[1] "2010-04-20 09:15:00" "2010-04-20 09:20:00" "2010-04-20 09:25:00"
```

Comment: Thanks, the function `strptime` is really helpful! I am dealing with time series data at first time, it looks complicated.

Comment: @thelatemail, all that `substr` stuff is not really necessary, is it? As long as the length of the final character string is correct, `strptime` should be able to parse the date fine, without having to have dashes embedded into the string.

Comment: @mrdwab - yeah, you're right. When I'm no longer trying to type on a phone I'll fix it up to just reference test$V1 instead of the substrings.

Answer (score 3):

First, fix your formatting and use a package like `xts` to get a proper time series object:

```
# Read in the data. In the future, use `dput` or something else
# so that others can read in the data in a more convenient way
temp = read.table(header=TRUE, text=" V1  V2   V3
1 20100420 915   120
2 20100420 920   150
3 20100420 925   270
4 20100420 1530  281")

# Get your date object and format it to a date/time object
date = paste0(temp[[1]], apply(temp[2], 1, function(x) sprintf("%04.f", x)))
date = strptime(date, format="%Y%m%d%H%M")

# Extract just the values
values = temp[[3]]

# Load the xts package and convert your dataset
require(xts)
xts(values, order.by=date)
#                     [,1]
# 2010-04-20 09:15:00  120
# 2010-04-20 09:20:00  150
# 2010-04-20 09:25:00  270
# 2010-04-20 15:30:00  281
```

In the date conversion:

- `apply(temp[2], 1, ...)` goes row by row for the second column of temp and reformats the number to be four digits.
- Then, `paste0` combines all the date-time information to a single vector.
- Finally, `strptime` converts that character vector to an appropriate date-time object.

## Update

Of course, if you want just a normal `data.frame`, you can do that too, but I strongly recommend using something like `zoo` or `xts` if you want to do real time series analysis.

Here's the simple `data.frame` step (following after creating the `date` and `values` objects earlier).

```
data.frame(V3 = values, row.names=date)
#                      V3
# 2010-04-20 09:15:00 120
# 2010-04-20 09:20:00 150
# 2010-04-20 09:25:00 270
# 2010-04-20 15:30:00 281
```

Comment: Thanks! I must spend more time on it.

Comment: Now for the "DUH" moment that comes after posting... Simplify to one line. For `xts`: `xts(temp$V3, order.by = strptime(paste0(temp[[1]], sprintf("%04.f", temp[[2]])), format="%Y%m%d%H%M"))` and for a `data.frame`: `data.frame(V3 = temp$V3, row.names = strptime(paste0(temp[[1]], sprintf("%04.f", temp[[2]])), format="%Y%m%d%H%M"))`.